# gulp-ruby-sass - 'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: css, ruby, sass, gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

I'm trying to run gulp-ruby-sass on Windows.

I've already installed Ruby and Sass like that:
`$ gem install sass`

My gulp.task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
   return sass('src/scss/**/*.scss')
     .on('error', sass.logError)
     .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

When I cd into the root directory of my project and run `$ gulp styles`,
I get this:

```
[22:54:52] Using gulpfile c:\wamp\www\wordpress\
wp-content\themes\bootscores\gulpfile.js
[22:54:52] Starting 'styles'...
[22:54:52] 'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error in plugin 'gulp-ruby-sass'
Message:
    Gem undefined is not installed.
[22:54:52] Finished 'styles' after 89 ms
```

I've been searching for a solution to this problem for about two hours now and still haven't found one that would help me.

Answer (score 11):

I've finally found a solution.

I had to manually add a path to my Ruby bin folder in  Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables. Here i added a new variable named path with a path to my Ruby bin folder (C:\Ruby22-x64\bin).

Then I restarted my Node.js command prompt and got the output I was looking for.

Thank you, CDF, for you answer and effort!
Even though I answered this question myself, I hope it will eventually help other people too.

Comment: I was trying to solve it on my side and I cannot get this error :) I upvote your own reply

Comment: @ZachSaucier Yes, finally I got this working! **Restarting the command prompt** as the answer says was my issue.

Comment: I installed sass https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and had the environment variable in place as well like `PATH=C:\Ruby23\bin;%PATH%`. The issue in my case was to also run `npm install -g gulp-ruby-sass`.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error, only in my situation `sass` package wasn't installed in RubyGem.

You need to execute following command:

```
gem install sass
```

Answer (score 4):

[image: INSTALL RUBY]

Use the Ruby installer and reinstall it. Then check the path checkbox. It should be resolved then.

2. Install Sass Using the Command Prompt

   [CMD] + [R]
   type cmd hit [ENTER]

   Type gem install sass

If you get an error message then it's likely you will need to use the sudo command to install the Sass gem. It would look like:

sudo gem install sass

4 Reboot the NODE command line. In fact you might want to reboot the system, most users do not do enough of that.